# how can I round to a multiple of a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I understand the Math.round/ceil/floor functions in javascript, I have been unable to come up with a working function to this problem.

What I want to do is round any whole number to a multiple of 3, or in fact any multiple which I choose.

The requirements of the returned numbers when the the multiple value of '3' is given are as follows:

```
0 returns 0
6 returns 6
7 returns 6
8 returns 9
22 returns 21
23 returns 24
```

etc..etc... So basically, the returned value will always be a multiple of the given parameter, in this case '3'.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a simple function like this:

```
function roundMultiple3(num) {
  return(Math.round(num / 3) * 3);
}
```

This divides by 3, rounds to the nearest integer, then multiplies by 3 again to restore the full value.

Or a generic version that allows you to specify the multiple:

```
function roundMultiple(num, multiple) {
  return(Math.round(num / multiple) * multiple);
}
```

Comment: How embarrassingly simple.  Math was never my strong point.  Although all the answers given appear correct, I believe you just pipped the others to the post by a matter of seconds.  Regardless... Thanks to all who have answered.

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine:

```
function roundToNearest(number, multiple) {
    return Math.round(number * multiple) / multiple;
}
```

To round to the closest multiple less than the number, replace `Math.round()` with `Math.floor()`. Likewise, `Math.ceil()` will round up to the nearest multiple.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
function roundTo(n, x) {
    return Math.round(x/n) * n;
}

roundTo(3, 2); // 3
rountTo(4, 7); // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Number.prototype.roundup=function(factor){
  var n=Math.ceil(this);
  while(n%factor)++n;
  return n;
}
```